# Capturing a screenshot of ubuntu system running on a virtualbox

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm running virtualbox on my Windows 10 to use Ubuntu. Now, I want to take a screenshot of a data inside the virtualbox. I know how to take a screenshot in virtualbox but I don't know where to find the screenshot in my Windows.
Anyone knows how to take a screenshot and save it to windows?

Comment: Don't capture the screen inside the VM. Capture the screen from the host while the VM is visible on the screen. Using a program like Greenshot (installed on the host) can make taking screenshots easier. Otherwise, as with anything else you want to exchange between the VM and the outside world, you will have to transfer the data via some method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows 10 to take the screenshot the PrintScreen button only copies the screen to the clipboard. In that case you will have to open an app like paint and paste it in. You could use the windows key + printscr key and it will automatically save a file to your pictures folder. Both of the above capture the whole screen with as many monitors as you have displayed. The last one that comes to mind is alt + printscr keys. This will capture the active window to the clipboard. Again you'll have to open a photo editing app like mspaint and paste in the picture to save it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Windows support for screenshoot is pretty primitive.
I would recommend using one of the numerous free third-party products that
are to be found which allow full control of all aspects, including store,
edit and upload to the Web.

See the article
[Best Free Screen Capture Tool](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-screen-capture-tool.htm).
My favorite is [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/).